# Chrome doesn't remember vertical scroll position of my website when reloading the page?

Tags: cache, google-chrome, usability, user-friendly

Chrome seems to remember the last vertical scroll position of most websites when reloading the page or going back to it from another page. However, it's not working on my site.

The site is a fairly simple server-side generated layout, not using any client side rendering at all.

What could be causing such a behaviour?

Comment: What cache control mechanisms do you use?

Comment: "going back to it from another page" - by hitting the [Back] button. Simply going "back to it" by following a link won't retain the vertical position. I would have said this must be dependent on the client-side browser cache (since you say you have no JS? Or just no client-side _rendering_?) - if you disable all client-side caching then I don't see how the browser can "remember" where the vertical position was? However, having tried to reproduce this behaviour myself by supposedly disabling caching, I cannot reproduce it - the browser always remembers the vertical position?!

Comment: Please add the HTTP response headers that your page is returning.

Answer (score 4):

In my case was a css issue at body (Firefox, Safari not affected by the problem):

```
overflow: auto;
```

After I remove it, it seems to work well.

Comment: For me, it was `overflow-x: hidden;` (which we added to avoid IE from showing a horizontal scrollbar).

Answer (score 1):

I am searching for the solution for the same problem. As you said, It happens when html code generates in JS. Browser doesn't find where to go (because html codes hadn't been generated yet.) and it goes 0,0.

I solved the problem with the min-height. I added a min-height value to the body code in CSS.

And, this is my first post in StackExchange. :)